# How to apply custom signout page when using default sign in page in sharepoint 2013

Tags: custom

I am using only windows authentication and used default sign in page. However, I want to redirect user to my custom sign out page on clicking of sign out button. 
Please let me know what to do.

Comment: If it helps, in my page I have a link to 
    http://myservername/_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true
The user gets logged out and prompted for a new login.